# How to fix rotten wood hole near sink?

Tags: wood, sink

I’ve got a nasty hole near the sink.

I guess the water gets out after dish washing underneath and rots the wood.

Is there a way to fix this without having to replace the whole vinyl?

I can probably find the paint color but not sure how to fill up the hole. Much appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: Just patching will not last long.  Should start by finding how far damage is done and removing all rotted wood.  Then can start to rebuild it with new wood.  A picture from further away showing what it is will help also.

Comment: There are several way to patch holes in wood, which way is best is dependent on a variety of factors.  More details will help. Also it the cause should be addressed before any repairs are to be done.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but rebuilding sounds like a lot of work but this is in an apartment where I will move out from and management refuses to make repairs so frankly I kind of want something that will at least get it out of the way for least a year when we move out.

Comment: This looks severe enough that it could be considered a health concern. Check with your local inspection office. There's no good way to repair that without counter top replacement.

Comment: @isherwood At least in Canada in my experience, the health department is unlikely to do anything unless there is a significant amount of mold. The health department i used to work at would not even come out to look for a health hazard such as this unless it was over a square meter of black mold. If its an apartment, and management wont fix it, i would strongly suggest you not try and fix it. As a renter, any work done, even if its an improvement, can be considered damage that you can be liable for. Just move out if the situation is that bad and you have the opportunity to, sorry to say

Answer (score 1):

That bench is beyond economical repair, or practical, repair.
If all the rotten wood were cut out the hole would probably be three times larger.

As a band-aid get a scrap of Formica sheet (or similar kitchen laminate) and fix it to the surface with duct tape.  the tape may need to be renewed every week.

Answer (score 0):

With the information gathered from the comments, considering you are the tenant of an apartment, I would suggest not repairing things yourself under a rental agreement. In jurisdictions such as the US and Canada, doing work to fix things, even if it is an improvement, can be considered damage, and you can be held liable for that.

If you have informed management and they will not fix it, and as I understand you have the opportunity to move out, I would just leave the damage, and move out.

In the meantime, landlord-tenant board would be a better bet than the health department if you really want to try and push the landlord to fix this. I would not fix this myself, thats for sure.